# How to provide error details back to REST request?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 REST API application, we have SQL errors which are occuring during the request. However, since the requests are big, we are streaming the data back to the client, which means we have already returned the headers and HTTP response code. What's the right way to return an error back to the caller? These can be XML, CSV, or JSON documents.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to return an object or field inside of your JSON, XML, or CSV called "Error" and have it contain an array of strings which describe each error. With this implementation it allows the client to parse each individual error and generate a nice log file. While this does have its pitfalls (unable to react using HTTP layer handling), it can be powerful for developers to know exactly what is happening with their request server side.

Comment: thanks, I can see this working with XML or JSON, but how would this work with CSV? CSV is a fixed format for our purposes

Comment: So with csv you could have either the first or last row be the errors row and separate each error with a comma.

Comment: Alternatively you could have one final row with a single element that is the entire array of errors in string format. Something like 

```
490    "Error: [ 404 Resource Not Found, 403 Forbidden, 400 Bad Request ] "
```